# Need normalized distance between geometry bounds

Tags: node-editor, shaders, mathematics

I would like to get a value between 0 and 1 of the distance between the mesh bounds in an axis (Y), depending on the X value. not sure this is crystal clear but the screenshot says more than words :)

[image]

the result should look like this (roughly) and be the same moving, rotating or scaling the object.
[image]

And I want that to be done with math and vector nodes in a shader, no script.

Comment: What happens if your mesh has a hole?

Comment: @maddin45 it's not supposed to happen...yet :)

Comment: @Bithur Hi, still alive ?! : P

Comment: @Chebhou more or less :)

Answer (score 1):

The closest thing I found is:

[image]

The diagonal highlights can be edited in the UV map

[image]

Comment: you're "cheating" with the UV map. The idea is to get the info from the mesh with nodes, not deforming a UV map or the mesh. But thx for trying :)

Comment: @Bithur yes, everything I tried with generated texture coordinates looked like a simple gradient and won't be black (0 value) at the bottom of middle edge.

Comment: This can give a reference as the object is contained in generated coordinates from 0 to 1. You can get the vertices position with "geometry" node (position output) but in world coordinates...

Comment: have a look at others "maths" tagged questions/answers

Comment: @Bithur Actually UV seems ideal here. BTW, you needn't destroy anything existing, because you can handle it with a second UV data, something like **[this](http://www.pasteall.org/pic/show.php?id=83858).**

Comment: @LeonCheung the problem is not doing something like this (it's quite easy to play with UVs and color ramps) but using the mesh data to achieve this effect on any mesh, with math and vector nodes.

Comment: @Bithur I experimented with the geometry node / parametric socket but it seems not possible to achieve this. See http://www.blendswap.com/blends/view/41864 it would be possible for triangles but not for quads.

Comment: @stacker The mesh can be triangulated, this is not a problem. This won't modify the position of the vertices.

Comment: @Bithur the problem is that the barycentric coordinates don't start at the same edge, you can see this when you connect a parametric output to a shader.

Comment: @stacker any clue on where to find informations on geometry inputs? blender doc don't say much about them